# Logical value of an assignment in C

Tags: c, coding-style, logical-operators, variable-assignment

```
while (curr_data[1] != (unsigned int)NULL &&
    ((curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1]) || 1))
```

Two part question.

What will `(curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1])` evaluate to, logically. `TRUE`?

Also, I know its rather hack-ish, but is the `while` statement legal C? I would have to go through great contortions to put the assignment elsewhere in the code, so I'd be really nice if I could leave it there, but if it's so egregious that it makes everyone's eyeballs burst into flames, I'll change it.

Comment: I think you should send this to "The Daily WTF".

Comment: have a heart for the poor soul who will have to read these lines,  it might even be you in 6 months time

Comment: Ummm... the bleeding eyes thing.  Yeah, definitely the bleeding eyes.

Comment: Andy, check your facebook.  Maybe you know who this is by the name (sorry everyone from comment spamming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. It will evaluate to true if `curr_ptr` isn't set to `NULL` (i.e. `curr_data[1]` isn't 0).
2. I believe it's legal, but there are bigger problems with this line of code.

Anyway, I'm assuming you didn't write this code, because you're debating about leaving it in vs. taking it out. So I want you to find out who wrote this line of code and introduce them to a heavy blunt object.

1. `(unsigned int)NULL` is ridiculous. Why would you do this? This will probably be the same as just writing `0` (not sure if that's guaranteed by the standard).
2. What kind of data is in `curr_data[1]` if it's being cast to a pointer (and pointers are being cast to it)? If it's supposed to be holding a pointer as an integral type, you should use the type `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` provided in `<stdint.h>` for that purpose (if you're compiler doesn't support C99 `ptrdiff_t` may be an acceptable substitute).
3. The `|| 1` at the end seems to be redundant. If `curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1]` would have evaluated to false, we would have caught that in the first condition.

It may be a pain in the ass, but seriously reconsider rewriting this  line. It looks like an entry in the IOCCC.

Comment: Haha, heavy blunt objects have been applied to this person already in the form of a kick out of the door. Anyway...
1. casting `NULL` as an `unsigned int` prevents the warning `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`. I just left it in to avoid retyping half the program.
2. Good idea. I'll see if I can make that change without breaking too much else.
3. Yea, I was wondering about that, especially in light of the first response I got.

Comment: If you have to do a cast there, cast `curr_data[1]` to a pointer type to better reflect how you're going to use it. However, if it held 0, casting it to a pointer will yield `NULL`, so you can just as easily do `curr_data[1] != 0` or even `curr_data[1]` and have the same logical check. My personal, hopefully more readable rewrite: `while(curr_data[1]) curr_ptr = (void *)curr_data[1];`

Comment: And the version that works knowing this is part of a `do {} while` loop: `do { ... } while(curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1]);` Alternatively, if you need to have a non-trash `curr_ptr` after your loop is over: `do { ... } while(curr_data[1] && curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1]);` Hopefully that should work.

Answer (score 3):

`(curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1])` will evaluate to TRUE unless it is a null pointer.

Assuming that `curr_data` is an array of pointers, and what you want to do is to run the loop while the second of these pointers is not null, while assigning its value to `curr_ptr`, I would do:

```
while ((curr_ptr = (void*)curr_data[1]) != NULL) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh, so my initial check is redundant, then? My initial check is to see if `curr_data[1]` contains null, but you're saying this would do the same thing?

Comment: No, because if the initial check fails then the assignment will never happen (`&&` has "early-out" semantics), and the while loop will exit.  Whereas the `|| 1` will make the while loop continue forever if you remove the initial check.  The `|| 1` is the bit that's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments are expressions in C, so what you have works.  Changing the `;` to `{}` means the exact same thing and is much clearer, do that change at the very least.  Assignments in conditions should be avoided when you have a clearer alternative (which is usually true), but if this is clearest in this place, then use it.

The result of an assignment is the assigned-to object.  `a = value` will do the assignment and then evaluate to `a`.  This is used to do things like `a = b = 0`.

To further clean up the code, there's no need for the void cast, and if this is chars, use '\0' (the null character) instead of NULL (which is supposed to be used with pointers only).

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't have to go through "great contortions", that is completely equivalent to

```
while (curr_data[1]) {
    curr_ptr = (void *)curr_data[1];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is part of a do-while loop.

Comment: @Andy - Aaaaaah! Here we are confronted with the real problem. I was wondering why we were looping to the end without doing any work.